# how to print n words of context while searching text

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk, grep

By way of analogy, I have used grep with -C many times. But it prints n lines of context. Instead I want n words. Any solution using perl / bash / any other commonly available tools is welcome.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The description of the above link says "When asking a question about a problem caused by your code..". But this is not a problem in my code. I want a solution for my problem as I do not have any code to show.

Comment: And this is not a code writing service. But assuming I was willing to write the code for you (after all it is one or two lines), how can I verify it does what you're trying to do without even an input/output example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can slurp whole input:

```
perl -e'undef$/;
        $a=<>;
        print "$_\n" for $a=~m/(?:\b\S+\b\s+){5}your regexp(?:\s+\b\S+\b){5}/sg
      ' <input
```

-- 5 words of context.